# Flagging an answer sometimes don't show the reasons list

Tags: support, flags, answers

why when flagging an answer the flag reasons list sometimes isn't shown and instead I have to choose

```
other (needs ♦ moderator attention)
```

And I have to enter the reason in the text box. Sometimes I simply wanted to choose

```
it's not an answer or a very low quality.
```

So why for some post, some options in the list disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the post is already deleted by the OP himself. Refresh the page to see that.

Comment: Question was for answers

Comment: My comment was orignaly because you said "it was closed". Answers can't be closed. But you fixed that.

Comment: General rule of thumb: if what you're looking for isn't there, refresh the page.